# Trying to get an XML file with attached styles on an XSL file with Angular does not seem to work

Tags: xml, angular, xslt

Im trying to fetch the data of an XML file that is stored under assets folder.
i have included in the assets folder an XSL file with all the styles that i want to apply on the XML file. and in fact when i preview it directly on the browser it works.
but what i want is to fetch the data with http.get from the assets folder, and then it only gives me the data without the styles.

What's happening?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an `<?xml-stylesheet?>` processing instruction in the XML instances, then browsers will use that as a signal to transform the XML using the specified stylesheet, but server-side software generally will return the XML document "as is" unless you somehow instruct it to do otherwise. It's easy enough to set things up on the server to do the transformation, but the exact way of doing it depends on what technology you are using server-side.